# Git: How to filter to only check for changes on a single file, from recent commits

Tags: git, file, commit, history, git-extensions

I would like to know, how to see only the changes that an individual file within a large repo, has gone through. And how to possibly revert the last x commits on it

I use Git Extensions mainly, but can also work with git bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a list of the commits for `path/to/file.txt`:

`git log -- path/to/file.txt`

When you've found the commit you want to revert the file to by using `git log` you need to get the first 7 characters in the SHA. It will look something like: `b81eb8e`. Test that you have the correct SHA by running (replace example SHA with your SHA):

`git show b81eb8e`

When you have confirmed the SHA run:

`git checkout b81eb8e path/to/file.txt`

Then the file is reverted on your file system, and the last thing you need to do is to commit this new edit.

Comment: and earlier version of this answer included an inelegant manual way to achieve the same. I felt that was lazy so I edited my own answer