# How to restore previous files and changes

Tags: git

My workflow is:
I make commits to branch main on local, I push changes.
I have automated merge on github and pull on serwer.

I want to restore some files how it was in second commit after init.
How to do this?

Comment: You can get a specific version of a file usinf `git checkout <commit/ref sha> <file>`.

Comment: thank you. and what should i do after this command. I want to restore all files to commit state and push,pull.

Comment: after checkout all files to commit i pushed, pulled on server: and i get:
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
Aborting

Comment: Seems like you did not start this step on a clean repo. There is some more details to these steps here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67726323/git-how-to-filter-to-only-check-for-changes-on-a-single-file-from-recent-commi/67729141#67729141

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I revert a Git repository to a previous commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-do-i-revert-a-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit)

Answer (score 1):

The advantage of using version control systems like `git` is that it captures the entire history and you can always go back to the code in a particular snapshot.  To do this:

1. Find the code point in the history that you want to get the files from.  Use `git log` and likely with `--all` to find the point in time with the sha identifier you want to get the files from.  If the history is long, you might try `git log --graph --decorate --all --oneline`
2. Then you can checkout that point in time using `git checkout SHAID`
3. If you want to get back to this point in time frequently, you might add a tag at that point so you can get back easily: `git tag MYTAG`
4. After doing whatever you want, go back to the main branch tip again using `git checkout main`